# Double-sided flipping invitation card for mobile/desktop users

Tags: image, animated-gif, flipper

How to create an electronic invitation card with flip page turning style.

I want to present double sided eCard to my guests rather then hard copy.
I may create 50 cards with each guest name printed on individual card.

My guests should be able to view/play this file on either mobile or computer.
Is there any image format available that can be view on all platforum in flipping page style ?

**

1. The desired (flipping card) will not based/bound on any particular app/application.
2. Can be viewable on any platform i.e. Desktop/Android/iOS etc. (in flapping style)
3. Please tell me what other options are available to do this job (rather then Animated Gif).
4. Page Flipping feature is must (through finger tip / mouse)
   **

a. I tried using Powerpoint 2 slides with flipping transition. but it requires Powerpoint app.
b. Gif Animator is also not suitable as it auto play. While i want user to use his/her finger tip to flip the page.
c. I dont want to create web-page for each guest.

Comment: Independent of platform and viewable without a specific app, then it’s either a web site (HTML) or a PDF. i think this question might fit better on a different site of the SE network, I don’t see how it relates to programming.